# Bézier curves as portions of algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-curves, bezier-curve

Can every Bézier curve of any degree be defined as the algebraic (polynomial) curve of which it is a part and it's endpoints? If some Bézier's (such as those of degree $n$ or greater) cannot be defined as such, describe them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Given a planar polynomial Bezier curve $t \mapsto (x(t), y(t))$, you can find a polynomial $F(x,y)$ such that $F(x(t), y(t)) = 0$ for all $t$. Of course, this means that the Bezier curve is contained within the set $F(x,y) = 0$.

In the CAGD literature, the function $F$ is called the implicit equation of the curve, and the process of constructing $F$ is known as implicitization.

A good place to start learning more would be these [notes by Tom Sederberg](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch17.pdf).